# Prevent white edges during orientation change

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I reproduce this issue with the most minimal React-Native app:

```
render() {
  return View({style: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }})
}
```

When I rotate my phone, one side of the screen has a white section during the orientation transition. How can I color that area the same as the rest of the background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the RootView of your app, the default background color is white. You can change this to another color by using the following steps:

In this example we'll set the background color to **black** on iOS.

**Open `AppDelegate.m` located in `PROJECT_DIR/ios/Appname/` for editing.**

**Locate snippet that looks similar to the following:**

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"Appname"
                                           initialProperties:nil
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

**Add the following line of code immediately after the previous snippet:**

`rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

**The resulting code block should look like the following:**

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                moduleName:@"Appname"
                                         initialProperties:nil
                                             launchOptions:launchOptions];

rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

**BAM! RootView background color is set on iOS!**

This information and more is available from this blog post: [Changing the React Native RootView Background Color (iOS and Android)](http://moduscreate.com/changing-the-react-native-rootview-background-color-ios-and-android/) by Jay Garcia. (I believe the Android information in this post may be out of date, which is why I didn't include steps for Android).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah. It's pretty lame that React-Native doesn't solve this with a JavaScript API. I wonder if this could be turned into an npm module and if the color can be changed dynamically throughout the application.

Answer (score 6):

I created a library, it allows you to do it from the level of JavaScript, and also allows you to do dynamic changes.

https://github.com/johniak/react-native-root-view-background

```
import { setRootViewBackgroundColor } from 'react-native-root-view-background';

export default class Main extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        setRootViewBackgroundColor('#ccc');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are referring to here. But what ever is containing that view needs to have its background set also perhaps?

Comment: Could you help me clarify my question? I don't know what other details could help. There is nothing containing the view. It is the root component and only component in the app and the issue is still present.